# Possible to keep one column outside of a row in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css-float, zurb-foundation, multiple-columns

This has puzzled me for a while.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have two columns side by side in Foundation, where one (say eight columns on the left) is within the .row and the other (say four columns on the right) is pushed right to the edge of the page?

I'd like to have a body of text that aligns nicely on the left hand side (hence within the row) and then lots of images running down the right edge of the page.

Just not sure if this is possible within Foundation or whether I have to use some other CSS wizadry...

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You "still" wanted to show something to the right of the 8 columns so what's stopping you from putting the images to the "rest of the 4 columns" on the same row?

Comment: Because they then won't sit on the right edge of the page, they will be within the row which has a set width

Comment: Can you sketch what you are thinking (or trying) to do and show it to us here?

Comment: Hi von, I added a screenshot, I have achieved this using a minus margin right on the images column

Comment: Looks like you can achieve it using the 12-column row. Do you intend to show the images beyond the twelve columns, is that your original question?

Comment: Yes, I would like the text aligned as a normal column within the row and the images flush against the right hand side

Answer (score 0):

SO is already telling me that we are extending our discussion, so without going into chat and with the understanding I have so far regarding your problem, let me give a shot at it. I've provided a sample code below. Your problem seems to be rather simple, at least based on how I see it, so let me know if I get it right. If not then it's best you edit your question and post the code you have so we can fix it. You need to use F4 for the code given below.

```
<div class="row">
        <h1>Short content on the left and lots of images</h1>
        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <p>Caramels tiramisu liquorice. Chocolate faworki brownie dragée wafer. Lemon drops tart bear claw wafer. Tootsie roll candy canes faworki lollipop bear claw bonbon sesame snaps jelly-o.  Danish sesame snaps toffee lollipop tootsie roll. Macaroon lollipop jelly-o pie gummi bears danish gummies jelly-o gingerbread. Pie croissant jujubes lollipop fruitcake icing. Fruitcake sweet roll cotton candy halvah gummi bears oat cake powder. Danish pudding toffee wypas bonbon macaroon lollipop faworki tiramisu.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <h1>Really long content on the left and few images on the right</h1>
        <div class="large-8 columns">
            <p>Lollipop chupa chups danish lemon drops lollipop pudding croissant caramels muffin. Chupa chups jelly beans sesame snaps sesame snaps gummi bears. Marzipan chupa chups faworki bear claw gummi bears. Tiramisu chocolate cheesecake jelly-o applicake chupa chups. Pie lemon drops ice cream sweet roll icing. Dessert tootsie roll carrot cake. Caramels caramels powder jujubes. Oat cake cheesecake dragée wafer sweet jelly-o. Lollipop donut cake candy chocolate. Pie candy canes oat cake powder carrot cake lollipop. Jujubes sesame snaps lemon drops cookie. Pastry jelly oat cake danish tootsie roll cupcake macaroon candy dragée. Cupcake apple pie dessert donut tootsie roll pudding. Jujubes lollipop wypas icing chocolate cake.
Pie apple pie caramels gummies cotton candy danish pastry bonbon. Croissant danish chupa chups wypas ice cream cookie apple pie sweet soufflé. Cake cotton candy wafer sweet roll oat cake cupcake. Sugar plum cake ice cream tiramisu sweet roll biscuit chocolate bear claw. Donut cheesecake tart apple pie dragée. Bear claw cake gummies faworki pastry jelly marzipan sugar plum chupa chups. Biscuit chocolate bar halvah oat cake topping wypas bonbon. Icing cake muffin apple pie chocolate bar. Gummies lollipop biscuit pudding pie cupcake soufflé toffee. Gingerbread tiramisu jelly wypas. Bear claw bonbon chupa chups chocolate cake tiramisu croissant chocolate chupa chups ice cream. Faworki applicake marzipan soufflé chupa chups donut. Tart gummies topping. Caramels pastry ice cream croissant fruitcake sugar plum.
Caramels sugar plum topping jujubes cake tiramisu sweet roll sweet roll cupcake. Tart wafer cupcake. Donut sweet dessert danish bear claw lollipop candy cheesecake. Toffee icing croissant. Gummies chocolate cake sweet chocolate bar pudding candy dragée liquorice. Jelly-o jelly-o croissant cotton candy marzipan chupa chups biscuit chocolate cake dessert. Marshmallow gummies sugar plum dessert. Applicake jelly cheesecake cotton candy ice cream cheesecake muffin marzipan. Cheesecake cupcake cookie marshmallow icing. Marzipan croissant carrot cake. Faworki candy canes jelly chocolate bar muffin. Bear claw biscuit chocolate cake sugar plum sweet sweet macaroon. Brownie liquorice gummies lemon drops cookie apple pie lemon drops chocolate bar chocolate bar. Sweet roll dessert sesame snaps jelly beans wafer.
Croissant tiramisu pudding cheesecake. Chocolate sweet roll gingerbread gingerbread muffin wafer sugar plum tiramisu. Wafer chocolate cake bear claw applicake wafer. Cupcake cookie bonbon. Sweet jujubes chocolate cake cheesecake danish chocolate cake pie wafer tart. Biscuit croissant wypas lollipop soufflé croissant soufflé. Carrot cake gummies toffee cookie. Wypas pudding chocolate bar jujubes. Icing apple pie pudding wypas bonbon carrot cake. Dessert cupcake marzipan gummi bears carrot cake candy. Cake jujubes jujubes cheesecake. Candy topping powder tart jelly-o. Sesame snaps cheesecake danish icing. Topping cake chocolate bar chocolate lemon drops candy bear claw marzipan.
Jujubes liquorice macaroon. Macaroon tart sweet. Donut caramels oat cake topping halvah. Jelly topping soufflé. Tootsie roll candy pie jelly beans applicake croissant. Tiramisu cookie sesame snaps. Pastry danish topping candy pie jelly beans cookie. Wypas pudding chupa chups cookie cake icing. Cupcake tiramisu ice cream gummies ice cream. Marzipan powder candy cookie faworki biscuit jelly-o toffee jelly-o. Cotton candy caramels pudding jelly-o chocolate cake sugar plum fruitcake cupcake applicake. Lemon drops liquorice bonbon wafer fruitcake cupcake cotton candy. Liquorice toffee jujubes pudding gingerbread biscuit.
Jujubes chocolate cake chocolate bar sesame snaps dragée. Biscuit carrot cake dragée gummi bears liquorice lollipop. Cupcake cake topping brownie gummi bears sweet danish carrot cake bonbon. Tiramisu cookie jelly beans toffee biscuit faworki danish sweet roll caramels. Sesame snaps jelly beans candy canes oat cake sesame snaps bonbon. Sweet cotton candy pudding pie ice cream dragée ice cream. Tart pudding marshmallow ice cream chocolate cake cupcake caramels. Marzipan caramels muffin jelly chupa chups bonbon faworki icing sugar plum. Pastry chocolate donut. Jelly carrot cake bonbon gingerbread. Cotton candy candy canes oat cake liquorice. Ice cream gummi bears dragée cookie toffee. Biscuit sugar plum gingerbread chupa chups chocolate bar pastry apple pie jelly sweet.
Tart powder cookie gingerbread icing cake apple pie. Topping danish halvah. Tootsie roll cookie pudding tootsie roll donut pudding toffee apple pie. Danish tart gummi bears oat cake halvah candy canes pastry marshmallow. Sugar plum jelly beans jelly-o pudding carrot cake chocolate cake donut. Fruitcake candy toffee sweet gummies dragée gummi bears tart macaroon. Powder danish liquorice danish biscuit. Oat cake brownie cheesecake wypas lollipop. Fruitcake cupcake biscuit sweet roll. Sesame snaps wypas dessert jelly donut jelly beans candy. Lollipop chocolate cake gummi bears bear claw fruitcake sweet. Pie toffee wypas.
Chupa chups powder bear claw cookie. Jujubes chocolate cheesecake jelly beans dessert icing chocolate cake wafer fruitcake. Marshmallow donut tiramisu lollipop. Muffin ice cream jelly liquorice tootsie roll pudding apple pie apple pie. Muffin cake sweet cupcake cotton candy carrot cake. Apple pie pie cookie powder bear claw tiramisu. Tiramisu jelly-o dragée bonbon sweet roll lollipop macaroon wafer. Oat cake bonbon chocolate cake. Soufflé cake fruitcake. Muffin bonbon cake apple pie cupcake jelly-o. Candy chocolate jelly beans cheesecake liquorice. Halvah jelly-o biscuit donut jelly beans faworki.
Tootsie roll bear claw soufflé. Apple pie fruitcake gummies. Applicake oat cake liquorice faworki apple pie tart cookie. Pastry halvah marzipan chocolate cake carrot cake topping. Cupcake tootsie roll cake. Pastry jelly pie. Chupa chups icing cake lollipop pastry brownie soufflé. Powder toffee fruitcake. Lemon drops icing cotton candy faworki cheesecake. Bonbon marshmallow brownie jelly. Chocolate bar marshmallow lollipop brownie. Pie soufflé tootsie roll chupa chups halvah jelly beans.
Gummi bears jujubes jujubes fruitcake dessert bear claw gingerbread. Ice cream lollipop dessert soufflé sweet roll carrot cake. Tootsie roll wafer cotton candy. Croissant cotton candy cupcake jelly-o sweet roll bear claw. Halvah croissant pie liquorice chupa chups croissant toffee. Cotton candy apple pie topping danish halvah jelly-o apple pie marzipan. Halvah pastry bear claw sesame snaps wafer faworki apple pie. Soufflé fruitcake soufflé sweet roll apple pie bear claw. Pastry oat cake gummi bears powder. Bonbon cupcake dessert. Croissant halvah soufflé gingerbread. Faworki caramels gummies lemon drops cookie. Toffee muffin apple pie.
Sweet roll jelly-o cupcake fruitcake cotton candy chocolate fruitcake fruitcake croissant. Oat cake dessert gummi bears sugar plum dessert soufflé donut carrot cake jujubes. Croissant lollipop chocolate bar sweet roll marzipan. Macaroon carrot cake tootsie roll ice cream ice cream faworki wypas chocolate bar soufflé. Wypas caramels candy muffin donut lemon drops dragée. Candy canes topping carrot cake toffee ice cream icing jelly-o sweet powder. Gummies muffin donut dragée tiramisu applicake jelly beans jelly. Danish donut marzipan croissant. Brownie tiramisu oat cake wafer cotton candy biscuit. Biscuit candy candy canes gummies candy croissant. Pastry sugar plum chupa chups caramels cake candy canes macaroon sugar plum halvah. Bonbon chupa chups sugar plum sesame snaps cookie sugar plum cake liquorice. Jelly beans lollipop sesame snaps ice cream chocolate cake pudding sweet chocolate cake topping.
Dragée dessert wafer biscuit oat cake brownie cupcake gingerbread. Pie gingerbread powder fruitcake lemon drops. Lemon drops candy canes pastry. Powder halvah danish candy canes oat cake. Jujubes caramels halvah cotton candy dragée jelly-o biscuit jelly. Candy halvah muffin muffin sugar plum caramels muffin jujubes jelly. Danish cookie cotton candy chupa chups danish tootsie roll pie. Chocolate cake wafer sesame snaps lemon drops. Sesame snaps pastry lemon drops fruitcake brownie. Dessert jujubes liquorice croissant croissant croissant. Biscuit pie donut lollipop danish applicake muffin applicake brownie. Chupa chups icing topping danish chocolate cake marzipan. Lollipop halvah wypas faworki donut pudding. Macaroon pastry chocolate bar icing toffee.
Bonbon bonbon lollipop gummies. Faworki ice cream pudding applicake topping chocolate cake. Candy soufflé candy sweet cotton candy pie. Caramels pudding brownie pastry gummies icing marzipan sweet. Sweet candy canes cotton candy dessert macaroon. Jujubes wypas macaroon. Macaroon biscuit gingerbread oat cake tart chocolate cake sesame snaps sugar plum. Fruitcake candy canes dragée pudding. Chocolate bar cotton candy sweet chocolate cake bonbon cotton candy liquorice bear claw. Pie oat cake cake topping sugar plum tiramisu cotton candy. Tootsie roll sugar plum candy topping croissant chupa chups pudding. Pastry lemon drops apple pie bear claw jelly-o topping.
Apple pie chupa chups marzipan. Soufflé lollipop marshmallow. Sesame snaps toffee tart cupcake donut candy chupa chups. Apple pie halvah chocolate macaroon bonbon. Croissant marshmallow liquorice chocolate bar gummies jelly-o pudding wafer icing. Chupa chups gummi bears tiramisu marshmallow marshmallow pastry fruitcake fruitcake cake. Bonbon ice cream marshmallow cheesecake pie tiramisu gingerbread candy cupcake. Ice cream jelly-o gingerbread dragée icing marzipan chocolate bar. Chocolate sweet bear claw faworki danish jelly. Cake marshmallow tart chocolate. Cheesecake jelly cotton candy oat cake sugar plum. Topping cupcake candy canes oat cake cookie. Cupcake cheesecake cookie fruitcake sesame snaps gingerbread marzipan candy canes candy canes. Croissant tootsie roll tart jujubes jelly-o tootsie roll danish jelly-o donut.
Jujubes toffee sesame snaps croissant jujubes. Faworki chocolate bar cheesecake carrot cake tiramisu topping marzipan dessert. Liquorice icing pastry wypas dragée jujubes jelly pastry. Carrot cake biscuit pie muffin dessert. Tiramisu oat cake wypas icing pie pudding dragée chocolate. Gingerbread fruitcake powder candy sugar plum. Chocolate dragée sweet roll cupcake sweet chocolate cake. Pie donut topping gummies fruitcake tootsie roll chocolate cake. Icing faworki chupa chups. Donut chocolate bar cake gummies donut chocolate cake sweet sugar plum. Chupa chups sugar plum marzipan jelly-o applicake. Icing pudding marzipan oat cake chocolate jujubes donut pudding caramels. Carrot cake sweet gummi bears apple pie carrot cake dragée oat cake. Muffin marzipan tart sweet roll cupcake cupcake.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="large-4 columns">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>
                <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Oh and of course the markup assumes that your list items are displayed inline.

**UPDATE:**
Have you tried something like this:

```
.row.flushed {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Von, though surely as the 4 columns is part of the row, it will be contained within the 1000px (or whatever the row width is)?

Comment: Yes that's right, so do you want it "beyond" the row's width limit but still on the same row (to the right)?

Comment: Yes von, as per original question, I need the images on the right edge of the page.

Comment: Yeah, there's no Foundation way of doing it. You said you did a negative right margin. I edited my answer in hope of providing an (alternative) solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, von I'll take a look at your solution.